# Time signature issue in MuseScore

Tags: time-signatures, musescore, anacrusis

[image: Time signature issue in MuseScore]How to add only one rest or note at the starting of the piece against the time signature without changing it in musescore?

Comment: Are you asking how to add an anacrusis?

Comment: Does this answers your question: https://music.stackexchange.com/a/82601/63781 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called an "anacrusis" or pickup measure.

1/ Easiest way is to add one when you start a new score, just tick the checkbox and add the value:

[image]

2/ Another way, e.g. if you already have created a score without a pickup measure, is to modify the first measure, by right clicking on it, then selecting "measure properties". There you can change the actual duration to 1 for example:

[image]

As was commented below, you should also tick the "Exclude from measure count" checkbox, since (as explained here: [Should pickup measures have measure numbers?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/96339/should-pickup-measures-have-measure-numbers)) pickup measures aren't considered measure 1.

Comment: The "Exclude from measure count" box should also be checked.